# Ubuntu Server TFTP on vitualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tftp

I know there are loads of similar questions and I have tried so many solutions none of which work!

I have my first Ubuntu Server virtual machine (12.04) to practice my PHP skills on.  I however can't get my php files from my host machine (windows 7) to the server!

I have tried installing: tftp, tftp-hpa, xinetd and a few others.

They all say "package is not an installation candidate. I have also looked at using shared folders but I cant get that to work either!

I know there isn't a lot of information here but I don't even know where to begin so let me know if any info will help!

Comment: you do NOT want to use tftp. xinetd itself has nothing to do with file transfers, it's a daemon to start OTHER apps. just go with ssh/sftp and forget anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're propably mixing up [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) and [TFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol). I think you're searching for an instruction to set up a normal ftp server. [Try this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/proftpd-installation-on-debian-and-ubuntu/).

If the server is reachable from the internet: Use a strong password, setup TLS / SSL and use your favorite FTP client software (e.g. [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) for Windows) to connect to the server.
If it's just a local development VM you can skip these steps.

Comment: Thanks!  I was only trying to use TFTP because my only (very limited) experience with linux was an embedded device that used TFTP.  I went for winSCP in the end